# Get user info(phone number etc) in LDAP with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, ldap

I'm looking how to get user info from LDAP server with PHP curl.
I think LDAP has ldap_search() function but PHP curl hasn't.
PHP curl's function curl_easy_setopt() has too many options and I don't know their exact meanings.
Anyone had done similar work?
Or could you tell me some example code about this?

I searched example code and read PHP curl manual but failed.:(

Comment: To start with, why do you want to do this _with curl specifically?_

Comment: I want 1) LDAP auth 2) get user info from LDAP server and make address book. With curl, I made LDAP auth but I don't know how to get user data from LDAP server with curl.

Comment: Okay, but once again, **why do you want to do this with PHP curl,** instead of the PHP LDAP module?